# Meaning of "ostensibly"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage, word-meaning, adverbs

Does "ostensibly" mean "apparently", "apparently, but not actually" or "apparently, but (most likely) not actually"? If different meanings are possible, then which one is the most common? And how can I use context to infer the intended meaning?

Although my question is general, it occured to me while reading  [this footnote](http://goo.gl/uTDBlL) on page 12 of *Mathematical Logic*
by George Tourlakis:

> † A finitist – and don’t forget that Hilbert-style metatheory was finitary, **ostensibly** for political
>   reasons – will let you have as many integers as you like in one serving, as long as the serving
>   is finite. If you ask for more, you can have more, but never the set of all integers or an infinite
>   subset thereof.

Comment: What does a dictionary tell you?  Ostensible is used when you don't want to divulge the real meaning for doing something, so you use a different reason- one that makes sense to people when they hear it, but that isn't your true motivation.  If I want to go to the store to get some candy, but I know my mother needs a loaf of bread,  I can volunteer to go to the store- ostensibly so that I can be a good boy and get my mother some bread, but really so I can buy some candy while I'm there.

Comment: @Jim Agreed. You can also view the situation from an outsider's point of view--your mother might suspect you're really going for the candy, but she isn't sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ostensibly* means *avowedly; professedly; apparently, but perhaps not actually.*

Or to quote [the Oxford Dictionary Online (ODO)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ostensibly):

> *Apparently or purportedly, but **perhaps** not actually*

You are correct to discern that there is ambiguity involved. The only way to resolve this ambiguity is for the person whose motives are questioned to explain his motive.

Otherwise, *ostensibly* can mean that the speaker (or writer) has some doubts about the professed motive. But it does not mean that the speaker is correct in his assumption.

Also, a speaker (or writer) may have no personal opinion on the matter, but is merely using *ostensibly* because others have called into question the person's motive. In this case, the speaker/writer has a neutral stance.

Comment: Another phrasing that might help is "to all outward appearances". It appears to be for a particular reason, but we aren't really sure that is the primary or only reason.

Answer (score 0):

When someone does something for an *ostensible* purpose, that purpose is not the real reason for their doing it.  They have ulterior motives.  The ostensible purpose is merely the face they have put on the situation when presenting it.

So, we can say:

**He took his wife out to dinner, *ostensibly to celebrate her birthday*, but his real reason was to get her out of the house, so the landscaper could plant  one of her favorite trees in the front yard while they were out.**

ostensibly to celebrate her birthday = the *purported* reason being to celebrate her birthday

Comment: -1 because *ostensibly* means *avowedly; professedly; apparently*, none of which **have to mean** that the speaker's statement (*ie* his claim, suspicion or viewpoint or allegation is true).

Comment: I agree with @pazzo that the answer misses a nuance to ostensibly. If I felt certain that the reason stated wasn't the true reason, I would use "purportedly". If I were talking about the most visible reason and suspected there were other private motivations in addition to them, I would use "ostensibly". That doesn't mean the ostensible reason is a meaningless or a lie, just that the advertised reason might not be the only or most important reason.

Comment: Did I say anywhere that an ostensible reason was a lie or meaningless? No. Does my example suggest that celebrating her birthday was a lie or meaningless? No. Does *purported* necessarily mean the thing purported is false? No, it does not. So youse guys are reading things into what I've written.

Comment: I'm not reading into what you've said, I'm trying to tell you that what you've written can give the impression that the ostensible reason is always not the real reason. I don't think you've explained the entire meaning; you've explained one aspect of it.

Comment: When used concessively, as it is in the OP's quotation about 'political reasons',  *ostensibly* means more than "to all outward appearances". The concessive use can be paraphrased as "*even though* to all outward appearances...". In that case, the judgment call that something is *ostensible* is not as wishy-washy as you're saying it is ("we aren't really sure...") A person who avers that something  or other is *ostensible* is  making an accusation or a revelation that there is a lurking subtext or a hidden agenda, or that some *pretense* is involved.

Comment: I think people sometimes write "ostensibly" when they mean "presumably".